# Case statement with DATEADD for over 24 hour calculation

Tags: sql, case, dateadd

I'm having a bit of a nightmare with a project at work. I'm pulling information from our rostering system using SQL. For whatever reason, the rostering system allows on call shifts to be created as ‘+0000 - 0700’ for example. This is returned at 24:00 - 31:00.

It's taken me days to identify this fact as the cause for my misery when testing the SQL. As soon as the routine hits one of these shifts it craps out with an ‘out of range error’ which makes much more sense now I've found the problem!

However, since I need to cater for weirdness in my code it's not as simple as telling someone to change their practice so the shifts over 24 hours no longer exist, so I was looking to manually interpret these problem times into something I can work with.

The following line makes sense to me but also fails with an out of range error:

```
SELECT
    RRP.shiftdate,
    CASE 
       WHEN RDS.SHIFTSTART > ‘23:59:59’ 
          THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -24, RDS.SHIFTSTART)
          ELSE RDS.SHIFTSTART
    END AS CLEANSED_SHIFTSTART
...
```

However, this crashes and shows this error:

> Conversion of a varchar data type to a date time data type resulted in an out of range value

Which part of the function is complaining?

```
CASE WHEN RDS.SHIFTSTART > ‘23:59:59’ THEN ‘ABOVE 24H’
```

This works well, but I can't work out the issue with the `DATEADD`, as I'm using it successfully elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Can you add a column to the schema? Do you have control of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to delete this answer, but it doesn't let me as it's been accepted. So I just I'm just editing it to say why it **shouldn't be used** and what was my **mistake**, I hope that's also useful:

I suggested using replace, and that works by the value, not the position, so if I had a time that is '28:59:28', it would actually be changed to 04:59:4

The solution that I wrongly suggested was:

This should do the trick, considering that you're using strings:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RDS.SHIFTSTART > '23:59:59' THEN 
                    CASE WHEN (CAST(LEFT(RDS.SHIFTSTART,2) AS INT)%24) < 10
                         THEN '0'+ REPLACE(RDS.SHIFTSTART,LEFT(RDS.SHIFTSTART,2),(CAST(LEFT(RDS.SHIFTSTART,2) AS INT)%24))
                    ELSE REPLACE(RDS.SHIFTSTART,LEFT(RDS.SHIFTSTART,2), (CAST(LEFT(RDS.SHIFTSTART,2) AS INT)%24) )
                    END
       ELSE RDS.SHIFTSTART
       END AS Cleansed_ShiftStart
```

This will work for any hours, so if you had a shift starting at: '49:34:54' that should be '    01:34:54'

But if the shifts will be, at the most, +7, then you could simply do:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN RDS.SHIFTSTART > '23:59:59' 
                THEN '0'+ REPLACE(RDS.SHIFTSTART,LEFT(RDS.SHIFTSTART,2),(CAST(LEFT(RDS.SHIFTSTART,2) AS INT)%24))                     
                ELSE RDS.SHIFTSTART
           END AS Cleansed_ShiftStart
```

Comment: Thanks, the string is only for display so (complex) some sums to maintain a date / time format are thankfully not required. I was definitely overthinking this one. Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually, you should use the answer bellow. I did a mistake with my answer. A part from the fact that I didn't know the option of using stuff(), I'm still a beginner :) there's a big mistake that I didn't think about. I'm using replace, and that works by the value, not the position, so if I had a time that is '28:59:28', it would actually be changed to 04:59:4. Sorry for the mistake, and I hope you didn't waste any time because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `shiftstart` value always starts with two digits, you can replace the first two digits with the number modulus 24:

```
select stuff(rds.shiftstart, 1, 2,
             left(rds.shiftstart, 2) % 24
            ) as cleansed_shiftstart
```

This doesn't convert the value to a time; if you want it as a time, the conversion will then be safe.

Not being a fan of implicit conversion, I might explicitly write:

```
select stuff(rds.shiftstart, 1, 2,
             try_convert(int, left(rds.shiftstart, 2)) % 24
            ) as cleansed_shiftstart
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help point you in the right direction?

I use a [Common Table Expressions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) below to dummy up some data.

This version can handle fairly wierd "time" values that range over "24:00:00" as well as "time" values that have no leading zero ("7:00:00" for example).

```
WITH s1
as
(
SELECT '31:50:12' as SHIFTSTART
       ,CAST(LEFT('31:50:12', CHARINDEX(':','31:50:12') - 1) as int) as my_hours_parsed
       ,SUBSTRING('31:50:12', CHARINDEX(':','31:50:12'), 10) as my_min_sec
UNION
SELECT '21:15:23' as SHIFTSTART
       ,CAST(LEFT('21:15:23', CHARINDEX(':','21:15:23') - 1) as int) as my_hours_parsed
       ,SUBSTRING('21:15:23', CHARINDEX(':','21:15:23'), 10) as my_min_sec
UNION
SELECT '7:00:00' as SHIFTSTART
       ,CAST(LEFT('7:00:00', CHARINDEX(':','7:00:00') - 1) as int) as my_hours_parsed
       ,SUBSTRING('7:00:00', CHARINDEX(':','7:00:00'), 10) as my_min_sec
UNION
SELECT '49:00:00' as SHIFTSTART
       ,CAST(LEFT('49:00:00', CHARINDEX(':','49:00:00') - 1) as int) as my_hours_parsed
       ,SUBSTRING('49:00:00', CHARINDEX(':','49:00:00'), 10) as my_min_sec
UNION
SELECT '99:23:00' as SHIFTSTART
       ,CAST(LEFT('99:23:00', CHARINDEX(':','99:23:00') - 1) as int) as my_hours_parsed
       ,SUBSTRING('99:23:00', CHARINDEX(':','99:23:00'), 10) as my_min_sec
UNION
SELECT '157:23:00' as SHIFTSTART
       ,CAST(LEFT('157:23:00', CHARINDEX(':','157:23:00') - 1) as int) as my_hours_parsed
       ,SUBSTRING('157:23:00', CHARINDEX(':','157:23:00'), 10) as my_min_sec           

)
SELECT s1.SHIFTSTART
      ,s1.my_hours_parsed
      ,s1.my_min_sec
      ,CASE WHEN s1.my_hours_parsed > 24 
            THEN 'Houston, we have a problem' 
            ELSE 'Works for me'
            END as SHIFTSTART_profile
      ,CAST(s1.my_hours_parsed - 24*(s1.my_hours_parsed/24) AS varchar(2)) + s1.my_min_sec as my_time_mod             
FROM s1;
```

This is the result...

```
    SHIFTSTART  my_hours_parsed my_min_sec  SHIFTSTART_profile              my_time_mod
1   157:23:00   157             :23:00      Houston, we have a problem      13:23:00
2   21:15:23    21              :15:23      Works for me                    21:15:23
3   31:50:12    31              :50:12      Houston, we have a problem      7:50:12
4   49:00:00    49              :00:00      Houston, we have a problem      1:00:00
5   7:00:00     7               :00:00      Works for me                    7:00:00
6   99:23:00    99              :23:00      Houston, we have a problem      3:23:00
```

Hope this helps